# Debugging an Electron app : Breakpoints not working ("Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found")

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, electron, breakpoints

I've got a basic HelloWorld app based on the [electron-hello-world](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) project running on VSCode and able to launch a debug session and the app starts up fine.

I've got a breakpoint set on main.js but it appears to be greyed out with a message:

```
Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)
```

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
      "port": 9222,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "diagnosticLogging": true,
       "outFiles": [
         "${workspaceRoot}"
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your generated code is present in "${workspace Root}" then outFiles should be `"outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/*.js" ]`.
For more info [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_6#_glob-pattern-support-for-source-map-setup)

Comment: Didn't help, unfortunately. Still stuck with the same problem

Comment: can you tell the path of main.js ?

Comment: My project is at /User/<name>/Documents/dev/electron-projects/electron-hello-world. The main.js is at the root of that directory (which is where ${workspaceRoot} resolves to)

Comment: can you try removing the port in configuration ?